# Computing the order of many elements together

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group of order $n$.

Procedure to compute the order of elements

- For $x \in G$
- Compute $x^2,x^3,\cdots,x^{k =\text{ord}(x)}$
- Now with the help of $x^{k}$ compute the order of $x^2,x^3\cdots x^{k-1}$ by using formula $\text{ord}(x^{k}) = \text{ord}(x)/\text{gcd}(\text{ord}(x),k)$.

**Claim :** If in the two step we went upto $k$ such that $x^k = e$ then we will compute the order of at least $k/2 - 1$ other elements ( new elements whose order is not known )

Suppose that we are storing the order of all the elements in a table. while computing the order of an element we will check whether it's order is already computed or not. In simple words in the third step we will compute the order of only those elements whose order is not known

I have tried like assume that $x$ generate the whole group $G$ in that case the above claim is true.  To me it appears that each time we are computing a subgroup generated by element $x$. I don't above claim is true or no?

Comment: It's true that each time you are finding the orders of all the elements in the subgroup generated by $x$. That won't be the whole group unless the group happens to be cyclic and you happen to have chosen a generator $x$. After that it's not clear what you're asking - so clarify by editing the question (don't respond in a comment).

Comment: Do you imply some specific sequence of picking elements? If no (that is, if we are picking them at random), then the claim does not hold. Think of a cyclic group of order 6.

Comment: You could do this more efficiently by using the prime factorization of $n$. For example, if $n$ is prime then just test whether $x=e$. If $x = pq$ is the product of two distinct primes, then you only need compute $x^p$ and $x^q$. If $x$ is a power of a prime $p$, then you only need compute $x^{p^i}$. You can compute large powers $x^k$ efficiently by computing $x^2,x^4,x^8$, etc and using the binary representation of $k$.